# How to make bottom navigation bar like Linkedin in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

LinkedIn Bottom Navigation bar

[image: Linkedin Bottom Navigation bar]

As we can see on the navigation bar items there is black scrollbar, In appbar we can make this by DefaultTabController() or just by controller property in TabBar but I am unable to find in bottom navigation bar,even I didn't find any package on pub.dev
So I want somebody Answer this with code

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Comment: In this package Style3 look

Comment: Thnx I find in style no 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an example, you can manipulate how the colors and how the labels are shown,
first make sure to extend TickerProviderStateMixin for example:

```
class _LandingState extends State<Landing> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
```

then create a TabController

```
TabController? con;
```

in the initState method type:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    con = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
    super.initState();
  }
```

the length is how many widget you have in Linked in there 5 so the length is set to 5

in the Scaffold widget add the following

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(
                25,
              ),
              topRight: Radius.circular(
                25,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: TabBar(
            controller: con,
            indicatorColor: Colors.red,
            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white,),
            labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 0,
            ),
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 11,
            ),
            tabs: const [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home_outlined,
                ),
                text: 'Home',
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                ),
                text: 'Notification',
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.app_registration,
                ),
                text: 'Information',
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                ),
                text: 'Settings',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

then in the Scaffold body:

```
TabBarView(
          controller: con,
          children: <widget>[
           Container(
              child: Text(con!.index.toString()),
            ), 
           Container(
              child: Text(con!.index.toString()),
            ), 
           Container(
              child: Text(con!.index.toString()),
            ),
           Container(
              child: Text(con!.index.toString()),
            ),
           Container(
              child: Text(con!.index.toString()),
            ),
         ],
),
```

make sure there are only and exactly 5 widget in the children of the TabBarView,
the same exact length you already set in the TabController.